# Angular Change Select Class After Selection

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Im new in Angular, and im trying to change the class and value of my  based on the selection using a (change) event however i dont know how to get the class changed from my typescript

Component.html

```
     <select class="btn btn-succes" (change)="status(model.estatus)"> //My Model Logic gets me a number from 1-3
                    <option value="1"> warning</option>
                    <option value="2"> danger</option>
                    <option value="3"> primary</option>
                </select>
```

Comonent.ts

```
  status(status:number)
  {
      if(estatus==1)
    {
      //Selected class now becomes btn btn-warning
      //selectect value now becomes 1
    }
      if(estatus==2)
    {
      //Selected class now becomes btn btn-danger
      //selectect value now becomes 2
    }
      if(estatus==3)
    {
      //Selected class now becomes btn btn-primary
      //selectect value now becomes 3
    }
  }
```

Comment: What actually happens when you run it? Based on the code you provided, I'm guessing nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(change)` event bound to classical input change event.

`(ngModelChange)` is the `@Output` of ngModel directive. It fires when the model changes. You cannot use this event without ngModel directive.

app.component.html

```
<select class="btn" [ngClass]="{
    'btn-warning': selectedStatus === statuses.Warning,
    'btn-danger': selectedStatus === statuses.Danger,
    'btn-primary': selectedStatus === statuses.Primary
  }" [(ngModel)]="selectedStatus" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
    <option [value]="s.value" *ngFor="let s of statuses | keyvalue"> {{s.key}}</option>
</select>
```

status.enum.ts

```
export enum Status {
  Warning = "1",
  Danger = "2",
  Primary = "3"
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

import { Status } from "./status.enum";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {

  selectedStatus = "1";

  get statuses() {
    return Status;
  }

  onChange(event: Event): void {
    console.log(event);
    // write your code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declate a property named `selectedValue` in your component and insdie your `status` method change the `selectedValue` based upon your condition.

```
<select
  class="btn btn-succes"
  (change)="status(model.estatus)"
  [ngClass]="{
    'btn-warning': selectedValue == 1,
    'btn-danger': selectedValue == 2,
    'btn-primary': selectedValue == 3
  }"
>
  <option value="1">warning</option>
  <option value="2">danger</option>
  <option value="3">primary</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

got it working after adding a HTMLElement on my component instead of just the value

```
estatus(elem: HTMLElement,estatus:number)  {
if(estatus==1)
{
  console.log(estatus, 'antes')
  elem.className='btn-success'

}else if(estatus==2)
{
  console.log(estatus, 'antes')
  elem.className='btn-warning'

}else if(estatus==3)
{
  console.log(estatus, 'antes')
  elem.className='btn-primary'

} }
```

COMONENT.HTML

```
<select class="btn btn-succes" estatus(demo,$event.target.value)" #demo> 
                <option value="1"> warning</option>
                <option value="2"> danger</option>
                <option value="3"> primary</option>
            </select>
```